# Navbar not fitting the whole page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, tiles

I have a problem that my navbar isn't fitting the whole page, as showed here:
It happened after I implemented Apache Tiles for templating

[image]

My menu.jsp is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Spring Boot</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/flight_information_display">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/flight_information_display/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Why navbar is not fitting the whole page?
I also used Apache Tiles for templating and my layout is:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- 
            <spring:url value="/css/main.css" var="springCss" />
            <link href="${springCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
             -->
    <c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss" />
    <link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

main.css

```
h1{
    color:#0000FF;
}

h2{
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

If you need any other code provided, please let me know.
Much thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">`? Or try to locate the `CSS` for `navbar` `navbar-inverse` and `container`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work out for me. Page still looks the same like it was before

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.full-width { width: 100%; }` class to your div so it is like this `<div class="container full-width">` . If this won't work then try to inspect your navbar classes so you can modify them in your CSS file.

**EDIT:**

This is the common navbar of bootstrap:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: How it looks]

Comment: That means that the navbar element should be modified or inspected. since the 100% width is so small. Try to inspect your `@media` classes too. Or make sure that you wrote `width: 100%;` and not `width: 100px;` or `width: 100;` . Keep playing with numbers and also try to add `width: 200%;`

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width to 100%. Try the below snippet

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Spring Boot</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/flight_information_display">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/flight_information_display/about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Screenshot (Stretched to 2 monitors)
[image]

**Edited**

Change the format of the above code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- 
            <spring:url value="/css/main.css" var="springCss" />
            <link href="${springCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
             -->
    <c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss" />
    <link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work out for me. Page still looks the same like it was before

Comment: Can you share your whole css script related to header? Should be some other framework or css property cause this. If you run the above snippet independently it works

Comment: I have added main.css

Comment: This problem occured once I added Apache Tiles for templating

Answer (score 0):

I suspect somthing in:

```
/css/main.css or  <link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is pulling everything to the left:  When you use the "container" class your menubar+nav should appear centered with padding each side.  looks like the padding is correct, but page is pulled left.

Note: container-fluid,  causes the layout not to have this centralized layout, with padding.

You problem lies in other CSS(main.css or ${jstlCss}).  You can use the F12 debugger to find the promlem.  look for styles that are removing the padding.
I suspect there is a class called "container" in you main.css

or  `<link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: I have added main.css code but there is almost nothing :o

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by changing my tiles layout.
I used divs instead of table

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- 
            <spring:url value="/css/main.css" var="springCss" />
            <link href="${springCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
             -->
    <c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss" />
    <link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you css code is:

```
 .navbar {
    /* ... (existing styles) ... */
    /* Add the following properties */
    width: 100%; /* Make the navbar take up the full width of the screen */
    position: fixed; /* Fix the navbar at the top of the screen */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```